# matching a variable when iterating another variable

Tags: powershell

There are two variables `$applicants` and `$students`. I wanted to iterate through `$applicants`, get the value of `Applicant`, `Location` and also tje name of the parent matching the name of that applicant from `$students`. Tried so far as below, but  couldn’t get the name of parent in last step. How should I be calling `$student` within the for loop of `$applicants`?

In this example, `$applicants` includes a name, location, address etc.

```
Applicant:John Taylor
Location: Newyork
Address: 7737 NW Inn

Applicant: Mark David
Location: Washington
Address: 101 S Parkway
```

`$students` have (name is same as applicant above):

```
Name: John Taylor
ParentName: Brian Taylor 
age:7

Name: Mark David
ParentName:  David Smith 
age:18
```

and so on …

Script:

```
$students = Get-Object admin
$students
$applicants = Get-Object admin
$applicants
$applicants | Select Applicant,
                     Location,
                     @{n='Parent';e={$students[$_.ParentName]}}
```

Output:

```
Applicant: John Taylor
Location: Newyork
Parent:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The objects in the `$applicants` list don't have a property `ParentName`, so `$_.ParentName` evaluates to `$null`. Also, `$students` isn't a hashtable in the first place, so the lookup `$students[...]` wouldn't return anything anyway. Because of this the calculated property `Parent` remains empty.

You probably want something like this:

```
$applicants | Select-Object Applicant, Location, @{n='Parent';e={
    $name = $_.Applicant;
    $students | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $name } |
        Select-Object -Expand ParentName
}}
```

If you want to be able to use a lookup like `$students[$_.Applicant]` you need to put the students list in a hashtable using the student name as the key:

```
$students_ht = @{}
$tmp | ForEach-Object { $students_ht[$_.Name] = $_ }
$applicants | Select-Object Applicant, Location,
    @{n='Parent';e={$students_ht[$_.Applicant].ParentName}}
```

Comment: Thanks much Ansgar. The first option almost worked for me. However the output now is as Applicant: John Taylor
Location: Newyork
Parent : @{ParentName=Brian Taylor}

How should I avoid the curly braces here and remove key name 'ParentName' from the output so it looks same readable format?

Comment: Read again. You omitted the parameter `-Expand` from my example.

Comment: Thanks again Ansgar, that helped. in fact i had two more variables (similar case as ParentName) which i wanted use along with the last line and it didn't work.